# optimizing the while loop with awk command

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk, grep

Can any one suggest me how to optimize below while loop which is part of a shell script.

```
function setvars() {
    CONN_TSMP="$1"
    USER="$2"
    DB="$3"
    IP="$4"
    HOST="$5"
    return
}

while read line; do

        TST=`grep -w $line $FILE1`
        ID=`echo $line | tr -d '\"'`
        VARS=$(echo ${TST} | awk -F '"' '{print $2 " "  $10 " "  $22 " " $20 " " $18 }')
        setvars $VARS

        if [ -z "$IP" ]; then
                IP=`echo "$HOST"`
        fi

        if [ "$USER" == "root" ] && [ -z $DB ]; then

                TARGET=/home/database/data1/mysql_audit/sessions/root_sec
                FILE=`echo "$ID-$CONN_TSMP-$USER@$IP.txt"`

        else

                TARGET=/home/database/data1/mysql_audit/sessions/user_sec
                FILE=`echo "$ID-$CONN_TSMP-$USER@$IP.txt"`

        fi

        ls $TARGET/$FILE
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
                echo -e "################################################################ \n" >> "$TARGET/$FILE"
                echo "$TST" | awk -F 'STATUS="0"' '{print $2}'| sed "s/[</>]//g" >> "$TARGET/$FILE"
                echo -e "\n" >> "$TARGET/$FILE"
        fi

        awk -F '"' '/"'$line'"/ {print "\n======================================\nTIMESTAMP=" $2 "\nSQLTEXT=" $10}' $FILE3 >> "$TARGET/$FILE"

done < "$FILE4"
```

According to my observation awk is taking more time.

Can any one help me how to write optimize the above code by replacing it with **awk code (an awk while loop which replace entire while loop shown above)** or by removing **awk** or **sed** or **grep** which take more time.

Comment: What shell are you using? (Bash, Dash, Zsh, PDKsh, Ksh, POSIX-Compatible, Original-Sh-Compatible, etc.)

Comment: Before you can optimize anything you have to measure your current performance, decide on your goals, identify what step(s) are responsible for the excessive time, and determine if any optimization is possible.  How have you measured performance, and how have you determined that `awk` is the problem?

Comment: bash shell....I have generated test cases and calculated time taken by each command with the test cases.

Answer (score 1):

1) In setvars(), Remove the double quotes around the assignments.   The double quotes force the shell to rescan the values.  This is minor, but in large shell scripts, it can add up to quite a bit of processing time.

2) You have multiple VAR=`echo $SOMEVAL`.  Just assign the value: ID=$HOST
FILE="$ID-$CONN_TSMP-$USER@$IP.txt"

3) You are running an external program 'ls' to check and see if a file exists.  Instead, use the builtin shell commands: if [ ! -f "$TARGET/$FILE" ]; then ...; fi.   If you want the output, just do an: echo "$TARGET/$FILE".

4) Open the output file once.   This is much faster, but can make maintenance of the script quite difficult.  Since you only have 4 echo lines, it may not help that much.

```
exec 4>>"$TARGET/$FILE" 
if [ ! -f "$TARGET/$FILE" ]; then 
   echo -e ... >&4
   ...
fi
awk -f ... >&4
exec 4>&-
```

It's not possible to optimize your awk without seeing the data it is processing.  You appear to have a more modern shell as there is a $(...) construct.   Replace any backtick usage with $(...).